# PhoneBootstrapperBase not available for windows phone 8.1

Tags: caliburn.micro

I have downloaded caliburn micro from within visual studio (NU packages). I am unable to add reference for "PhoneBootstrapper" but it is changed to "PhoneBootstrapperBase" but even then I couldn't add "PhoneBootstrapperBase" reference in Windows Phone 8.1, any one kindly tell me what to do. I have Google it a lot and read the documentation but couldn't find my answer.
any response will be highly appreciated,
thank you

EDITED:
this the issue I am facing here's the code screenshot 
[image]

and here is app.xaml

[image]

Comment: As far as I know you should create a custom bootstrapper class that extends `PhoneBootstrapperBase`. Have you tried that ? Also please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: i am facing the extension (inheritance) issue. I am not able to extent my class with 'PhoneBootstrapperBase'

Comment: yes I have used the right cases but I think it some other issue. see the screenshot

Comment: What's your app.xaml ?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of app.xaml plz check

Answer (score 0):

Which flavor of windows phone 8x?

Windows Phone Apps 8.1 (universal/ stand alone) follow the CaliburnApplication base class (reference windows phone 8.1 e.g. WPA81 or using the CaliburnApplication base class in the App.cs with samples in Windows 8x store development) and is more inline with Windows 8/8.1 development due to usage of the WRT.  Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 follows the Bootstrapper method...